# Flask: use flask-sqlalchermy paginate result error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My code looks like this：

```
page = db.session.query(agent).filter(...).order_by(agent.create_time).paginate(1, 10)
```

The result is: page.total is 9.

But when I change the code to this：

```
page = db.session.query(agent).filter(...).order_by(agent.create_time).paginate(1, 20)
```

The result is: page.total is 19.

---

The result of executing sql in the database terminal is 19

#### what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If the query wasn't wrong, show the `filter` conditions.

The `total` is the result:

```
db.session.query(agent).filter(...).order_by(None).count()
```

`total` has nothing to do with `page/per_page`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My query like this:
```  
   query = db.session.query(Agent) \
            .join(AgentRela, AgentRela.agent_id == Agent.id) \
            .join(AgentAccount, AgentRela.agent_account_id == AgentAccount.id) \
            .filter(Agent.status == 1, AgentAccount.status == 1, AgentRela.status == 1, 
            Agent.parent_id == agent_id, Agent.staff_id == staff_id) \
            .order_by(Agent.create_time).paginate(page, size)
```
Like the problem description above, change the size. The result data is missing, I don't know why this result